# How to resize a single JTable column without affecting the other table columns

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtable, tablecolumn

I'm trying to resize a JTable column without affecting the rest of the columns in the table but every time I try to do this all the other columns also change size:

```
    final JTableHeader header = (JTableHeader) e.getSource();
    header.getTable().setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
    TableColumn column = header.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);                              
    for (int col = 0; col < header.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() ; col++) {
        if (col == column.getIndex()) {
            header.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setPreferredWidth(header.getColumnModel().getColumn(col).getPreferredWidth()+100);
            break;
        }                    
    }
    columnModel.getTable().doLayout();
```

Comment: unrelated: no reason to manually call doLayout, that's handled automatically when the (pref)width of a column is changed.

Comment: and is about standard settings

Comment: btw: there is on method `tableColumn.getIndex()`, only _getModelIndex_ - so I don't quite understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change only one column's size then no need to do such long procedure. You can do it in a single line like:

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).getPreferredWidth()+100);
```